# How to automatically update changes from other project reference to current project C# - VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, reference, csproj

I am using Visual Studio Code for development of .NET Core web API project.

I have several class libraries in my project. i am trying to add reference of project library using following command

```
dotnet add reference ..//myProject/Library1/Library1.csproj
```

Once added Library1 reference to another library, if any changes are required on Library1 project, those changes are not automatically detected in another library, i explicitly have to remove the reference and add it again.

Are any settings required to automatically update changes from other library on VS Code?

Comment: Normally you'd have all the projects in a solution file and build the solution, then it handles the dependencies for you. Alternatively, you can manage the projects and their dependencies in an MSBUILD file, but that's a lot of work and means you have to manage the dependencies manually.